# Windows 2008 Server R2 NAT problems with VLANs

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, nat, vlan

My Windows 2008 server R2 has two NICs. First NIC is connected to my ISP (IP assigned with DHCP). Second NIC is dedicated to LAN communication and is connected to HP ProCurve switch "trunk" port with multiple VLANs (Vlan7 and Vlan8).

Configuration of these card are:

First NIC: All settings are from DHCP. (ISPs NIC)

Seconf NIC (Local Area connections):
 -LAN7: 192.168.7.1 Mask: 255.255.255.0 Gateway: blank
 -LAN8: 192.168.8.1 Mask: 255.255.255.0 Gateway: blank

(Pings from VLAN7 and VLAN8 workstations to server are successful, with such network configurations: PC1/ IP: 192.168.7.100 Mask: 255.255.255.0 Gateway: 192.168.7.1, etc. )

After enabling RRAS on Windows 2008 server with NAT option, I cannot get any of VLANs (VLAN7, VLAN8) gain access to internet (looks like Windows does not know how to translate address to send traffic to outgoing interface).

When connecting NIC2 to simple access port on switch, in this case removing VLANs, then NAT works great.

Looking for help, 
thanks.

Jānis

Comment: How are you handling VLANS? Windows Server 2008 R2 doesn't support them natively (unless using Hyper-V)... are you using some tool from the NIC vendor?

Comment: Yes, INTEL cards with INTEL VLAN management on NIC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem with the help of Hyper-V. In Hyper-V manager you have to use Virtual Network Manager and add those extra Microsoft Hyper-V VLAN interfaces based on NIC native VLAN interfaces.

Microsoft Hyper-V VLAN interface configuration screen in VMN
https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0sa1.png

Now I can access internet from any workstation connected to VLAN10 or VLAN7 in my switched network. Hope this helps someone!